# Как получить идентификатор сделки по номеру телефона и направлению сделки через API Битрикс24?

Tags: битрикс, битрикс24

Как получить идентификатор сделки по номеру телефона и направлению сделки через API Битрикс24?
Допустим, имеется сделка, нам нужно узнать ID сделки по номеру телефона или другим полям.
Документация https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/crm/cdeals

Comment: Номер телефона пользовательское поле? Или номер телефона Контакта/Компании прикрепленного к сделке?

Comment: Номер телефона прикрепленного к сделке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если сделка уже создана и получить id необходимо по номеру телефона контакта, то для начала понадобится узнать id контакта, так как в Битрикс24 после создания сделки в ней хранится только id контакта.

Поэтому сначала делаем веб-хук для получения id контакта по номеру телефона примерно так:

```
вебхук: crm.contact.list.json 
параметры:  
    { 
        order: { "DATE_CREATE": "ASC" },
        filter: { "PHONE": "CLIENT_PHONE" },
        select: [ "ID" ]
    }
```

сохраняете полученный id контакта и зная его можно вытаскивать id сделки

```
вебхук: crm.deal.list.json
параметры:
    { 
        order: { "ID": "ASC" },
        filter: { "CONTACT_ID": ид полученного контакта, "CATEGORY_ID": ид направления сделки },
        select: [ "ID" ]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Не указано для какого языка должно быть решение, но если речь идет об использовании REST API Битрикс24 в JavaScript или TypeScript-приложении, это можно сделать с помощью клиента [2bad/bitrix](https://github.com/2BAD/bitrix):

```
import Bitrix from '@2bad/bitrix'

const bitrix = Bitrix('https://PORTAL.bitrix24.ua/rest/1/WEBHOOK_TOKEN')

const listDealsIDsByPhoneAndCategory = (phone: string, categoryID: number) =>
  bitrix.contacts.list( {
    filter: { 'PHONE': phone },
    select: ['ID']
  })
    // Учтите, что контактов с таким номером может быть больше чем один
    .then(({ result }) => result[0].ID)
    .then((contactId) => bitrix.deals.list({
      filter: {
        'CONTACT_ID': contactId,
        'CATEGORY_ID': categoryID
      },
      select: ['ID']
    }))
    .then(({ result }) => result)

listDealsIDsByPhoneAndCategory('563555', 0)
  .then(console.log)
```